# How to match latex bibliography in python?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to get plain text from LaTeX source code and would like to remove bibliography. For example,

```
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{b0} J.Dunietz, J.Hauser, J.L.Rosner, Phys. Rev. {\bf D}35 (1987)
2166
\end{thebibliography}
```

I found out the `detex` module for the extraction but I'm still trying to remove the bibliography first (using python `re`). What I have right now is:

```
>>> b = '\newpage\begin{thebibliography}{99}\bibitem{b0} J.Dunietz, J.Hauser\end{thebibliography}'
>>> re.sub('\\\\begin\{thebibliography\}(.*?)\\\\end\{thebibliography\}', ' ', b)
'\newpage\x08egin{thebibliography}{99}\x08ibitem{b0} J.Dunietz, J.Hauser\\end{thebibliography}'
```

The ideal result here should be: `\newpage`. I wonder what am I doing wrong here? Thank you!

Comment: It seems to be taking the `\b` as an escaped-sequence. Look at the start of your resulting string: `'\newpage\x08egin...'`

Comment: @sshashank124 Thank you! I am new to regex and I wonder how can I match the whole "\begin{...}" in the string?

Comment: You seem to have manually supplied the string literal in your `re.sub` example. Can you please show how your actual code looks? And, try printing the value of your string before you pass it into `re.sub`

Comment: Something seems to be inconsistent in your string. Notice the difference between `\begin` and `\\end`. Can you please show how `b` gets its value?

Comment: I have edited my code. The `(.*?)`, as I understand, is used to match anything in between and the `\`'s are used to escape the special characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use raw-strings, to greatly reduce the mental load of dealing with escapes (especially when dealing with escaping at both the string and the regex level). Let's define `b` as a raw string (note the `r''`):

```
b = r'\newpage\begin{thebibliography}{99}\bibitem{b0} J.Dunietz, J.Hauser\end{thebibliography}'
```

Let's look at what we have in the string:

```
>>> b
'\\newpage\\begin{thebibliography}{99}\\bibitem{b0} J.Dunietz, J.Hauser\\end{thebibliography}'

>>> print(b)
\newpage\begin{thebibliography}{99}\bibitem{b0} J.Dunietz, J.Hauser\end{thebibliography}
```

The raw-strings seems to have escaped the backslashes properly. Now we can simply `re.sub` the pattern with an empty string. Again, we will use a raw-string to define  the pattern to simplify the escaping:

```
>>> result = re.sub(r'\\begin\{thebibliography\}.*?\\end\{thebibliography\}', '', b)

>>> result
'\\newpage'

>>> print(result)
\newpage
```

Comment: BTW, we were having `\newpage` before but we get `\\newpage` in the result. Is there a way to convert it back?

Comment: There's a difference between inspecting a string (in the REPL) vs printing the string. It should be `\newpage` when you print the string and that's what matters. The inspection just shows you extra control characters for how you would create the string if you were typing it in your code